# Easiest way to save Django´s formwizard form_list in DB?

Tags: django, model, save, formwizard

I have created multiple sub-forms from one model to use the FormWizard in Django.

Confusing is the saving part. Once the user finished the form, I wanted to save the information in the DB. This is fairly simply with one form, where I can say

> one_form_from_model.save()

But could I do it when I get a form_list returned. I read some postings but they did not make any sense to me.

Can I clean the data

> form.cleaned_data for form in form_list]

and then go through every form? But then I would need to know in which form I am to find the right fields. Isn´t there any easier way to do it?

Thank you for your advice!

Answer (score 8):

Try something like this:

```
instance = MyModel()
for form in form_list:
    for field, value in form.cleaned_data.iteritems():
        setattr(instance, field, value)
instance.save()
```

Comment: `inst = MyModel(**{key: value for form in form_list for key, value in form.cleaned_data.items()})` and `inst.full_clean()` then `inst.save()`

Comment: Or better: `MyModel(**self.get_all_cleaned_data())`

Comment: @GuillaumeLebreton Why?

Comment: Uh, its much more elegant to me, and also surely faster i think.